# Block not expanding vertically for inline padding

Tags: css

A simple block element won't expand vertically unless its contents are of inline-block or block.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4148xjvv/7/

Or see code:

HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <span class='padding'>Inline</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='parent'>
  <span class='inline-block padding'>Inline-block</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='padding'>Block</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

The lateral padding works, but the vertical does not.

Chrome debugger shows that the padding is there, but bleeds out of the parent.

[image: Chrome Debugger]

Obviously this isn't a huge issue, I can just change the children to inline-block if I need padding, so I want to know *why* this is happening.

Comment: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/ might help.

Comment: `block`, `inline-block` and `inline` are not valid html elements. Try using valid markup and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @sean [you can have custom elements in HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/). Though with his elements, `inline-block` is the only valid element, since it has a `-` in the name. A class would be better for this, but it shouldn't effect the rendering.

Comment: @JacobGray As described in your link, custom elements must be registered via javascript, which isn't happening in the above example. If the custom elements aren't registered, it's invalid markup.

Comment: Yep, for valid HTML you do have to register the element. But it is still rendered, even if you don't register it. The problem he is having is that inline elements can't have vertical padding. Replacing the element with a valid element has the same effect https://jsfiddle.net/4148xjvv/6/

Comment: The custom elements are not the issue, as @JacobGray has said. I only had custom elements to further show the effect, but I'll switch to classes to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @JacobGray Getting 500 Internal Server Error from your maxdesign link, and trying maxdesign.com/articles/inline (no .au) gives a 404 :/

Comment: Hm, works for me. It basically says what I said, If you want vertical padding, use `inline-block`

Comment: @JacobGray Vertical padding just _doesn't work_ for inline? And this is a conscious decision, yes, from W3?

Comment: @Quelklef Heh, just learned something new myself :P https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/ It does work, it just doesn't effect the elements position relative to the elements above and below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article to be very helpful in understanding what is happening: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/

> Any vertical padding, border, or margin applied to an element will not push away elements above or below it.

[image]

Basically, as you can see from the image above, the padding is added, it just doesn't change the vertical position of the element.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the padding to a `span` element, which is an inline element, where vertical padding won't move the element - its baseline (and therefore the text) stays where it is, due to the inline property of the span element.

therefore the vertical padding can only work in conjuction with the inline-block setting in your second parent element - or in your third parent element where you add it to a `div` element.

Comment: Can you add link to documentation?

Comment: But the side padding works, as you can see in the example. Also, if you use some debugging tool, it shows the padding bleeding out of the parent; aka the padding does work, kinda.